# What should I do to take good jewellery pictures with a Panasonic FZ45?

Tags: lighting, panasonic, product-photography, jewelry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I capture both sparkle and detail when photographing jewelry?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/18591/how-can-i-capture-both-sparkle-and-detail-when-photographing-jewelry)

I want to take good jewelry pictures with my camera (Panasonic FZ45). I currently have two stand lights and a tent — http://kwedsd.comlu.com/1.jpg

The pictures I would like to take should be similar to: http://kwedsd.comlu.com/2.jpg

Any advice achieving this would be great. (If at all possible).

Thanks

PS. I also have a Raynox DCR-250 Macro Attachment and the Panasonic Conversion Lens Adapter