# How can I capture both sparkle and detail when photographing jewelry?

Tags: lighting, product-photography, jewelry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the key things to think about when photographing jewelry?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2880/what-are-the-key-things-to-think-about-when-photographing-jewelry)

I have some *shiny stone* studded bangles and *diamond* rings.
I want to capture both the "*sparkle*" as well as the "*fine details*" of the rings and the bangles at the same time.

The problem is that to get the sparkle, I raise the shutter speed which darkens the total scene, and thanks to the zoom lens the aperture can't be lowered beyond 5.6 (in my point and shoot camera with noisy ISO).

In overall, it gets all dark.

How to photograph **sparkling** jewelery? Which lights to use in which way?

Even if I get a 1.4F prime lens will that be enough? Or is there some factor which needs to be taken care of?

Also, I want the fine details of the ring design preserved, so won't 1.4F be a problem?

Comment: please could whoever downvoted / voted to close add a comment to explain?  In particular, if this is a duplicate, please post a link to the duplicated question?  thanks.

Comment: I think this question can be merged with this one: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2880/what-are-the-key-things-to-think-about-when-photographing-jewelry. Not sure though but still I'll flag, lets see. :)

Comment: I'm in favor of erring on the side of creating a new question, but searching first and referencing related existing questions in your new one. See [this discussion on meta](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1712/how-do-i-refresh-a-question). If you do that, there's no shame if the community later decides that it really is a duplicate after all.